# Difference between sympy.symbols and sympy.Symbol

Tags: sympy

What's the difference between these similar-sounding methods?

```
import sympy
from sympy.physics.units.systems import SI
from sympy.physics.units import meter, second

A = sympy.symbols('A')
type(A)
B = sympy.Symbol('B')
type(B)

SI.set_quantity_scale_factor(A, meter**3/second)
SI.set_quantity_scale_factor(B, meter**3/second)
```

`A` and `B` have the same `type`, and both are acceptable as inputs to `SI.set_quantity_scale_factor`. Is this not a glaring violation of "[only one way to do it](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs, and if needed the code. Symbol is a class. symbols is a function that can create multiple instances of the Symbol class.

```
In [7]: symbols('A')                                                            
Out[7]: A

In [8]: Symbol('A')                                                             
Out[8]: A
```

`symbols('A B C')` is different from `Symbol('A B C')`.

```
In [9]: symbols('A B C')                                                        
Out[9]: (A, B, C)

In [10]: Symbol('A B C')                                                        
Out[10]: A B C

In [11]: type(_10)                                                              
Out[11]: sympy.core.symbol.Symbol
```

Defining a class, and a separate function (or syntax) to create object(s) of that class is fairly common in Python.

`np.array` makes a object of class `np.ndarray`.  `[]` makes a `list` object,  `{a:b}` makes a `dict` object.

Comment: You're right about reading the docs (although I thought I had done that). I don't think "read the code" is a good answer, though.

Comment: With `ipython` looking at the code of a function is as easy as reading the docs.  Some functions just deligate the action to a like named method (esp in numpy), but here that isn't the case..  The class definition of one is obvious, while the other spends a lot code one parsing the input string before doing a `type` loop.